# React Native Convert Text component to String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to convert  component into string.  Basically i integrated this https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-globalize library in my RN project because i want to add Multi language option in my application. This library is working fine with text components but when i tried it to add FormattedMessage which returns **TEXT** it shows error.

```
malformed calls from js
```

So, text component cannot be passed in Pickers (label) & on TextInput (Placehoder) attributes. My application is in final stages that is why i can't revert back. I tried like this to convert

```
const purpose = (<FormattedMessage message="purpose "/>).toString()
```

**return Empty Object**

```
const purpose = (JSON.stringify(<FormattedMessage message="purpose "/>)).toString()
```

**return error**

Is there a way in RN to convert `<FormattedMessage message="purpose "/>` or `<Text>Purpose</Text>` into string

Comment: Is there any reason not to pass only the string?

Comment: Because https://github.com/joshswan/react-native-globalize works like that